Signing a CloudKit web services request using the Web Crypto API
I am trying to authenticate a CloudKit web services request using the Web Crypto API.
I already have authentication using the node crypto API, and have verified this works:
import Crypto from 'crypto'

export async function cloudKitRequest(body, method, operationSubpath) {
    const subpath = `/database/1/${env.CLOUDKIT_CONTAINER}/${env.CLOUDKIT_ENVIRONMENT}/${operationSubpath}`
    const bodyString = JSON.stringify(body)
    const hash = Crypto.createHash('sha256')
    const sign = Crypto.createSign('SHA256')
    const date = new Date().toISOString().replace(/\.[0-9]+?Z/, 'Z')
    hash.update(bodyString, 'utf8')
    sign.update(`${date}:${hash.digest('base64')}:${subpath}`)
    return await fetch(`https://api.apple-cloudkit.com${subpath}`, {
        body: bodyString,
        method: method,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-Apple-Cloudkit-Request-KeyID': env.CLOUDKIT_KEY_ID,
            'X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-ISO8601Date': date,
            'X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-SignatureV1': sign.sign(
                env.CLOUDKIT_PRIVATE_KEY,
                'base64'
            ),
        },
    })
}

I have now converted this to using Web Crypto APIs and am getting "Authentication Failed" errors, indicating my request signature is wrong. I have already verified that my body hash is correct. This is my Web Crypto code:
const encoder = new TextEncoder()

export async function cloudKitRequest(body: any, method: string, operationSubpath: string, env: any) {
    const subpath = `/database/1/${env.CLOUDKIT_CONTAINER}/${env.CLOUDKIT_ENVIRONMENT}/${operationSubpath}`

    const date = new Date().toISOString().replace(/\.[0-9]+?Z/, 'Z')
    const bodyHash = await hashBody(body)
    const message = `${date}:${bodyHash}:${subpath}`
    const privateKey = await loadPrivateKey(env.CLOUDKIT_PRIVATE_KEY)
    const signature = await signMessage(privateKey, message)

    const headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-KeyID': env.CLOUDKIT_KEY_ID,
        'X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-ISO8601Date': date,
        'X-Apple-CloudKit-Request-SignatureV1': signature,
    })

    const options = {
        method: method,
        headers: headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
    }

    return await fetch(`https://api.apple-cloudkit.com${subpath}`, options)
}

const hashBody = async (requestBody: any) => {
    const encodedBody = encoder.encode(JSON.stringify(requestBody))
    const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', encodedBody)
    return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(hashBuffer)))
}

const b642ab = (base64_string: string) => {
    return Uint8Array.from(atob(base64_string), (c) => c.charCodeAt(0))
}

const signMessage = async (privateKey: CryptoKey, message: string) => {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder()
    const encodedMessage = encoder.encode(message)

    const signature = await crypto.subtle.sign(
        {
            name: 'ECDSA',
            hash: { name: 'SHA-256' },
        },
        privateKey,
        encodedMessage
    )

    return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(signature)))
}

const loadPrivateKey = async (pem: string) => {
    const binaryDer = b642ab(pem)

    const importParams = {
        name: 'ECDSA',
        namedCurve: 'P-256',
    }

    return await crypto.subtle.importKey('pkcs8', binaryDer.buffer, importParams, true, ['sign'])
}

Following the guidance here, my private key was generated using openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out eckey.pem. In the node crypto example, env.CLOUDKIT_PRIVATE_KEY is set to the exact contents of eckey.pem and works correctly. In the web crypto example, I have tried both these contents and converting to pkcs8 using openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in eckey.pem -out eckey_okcs8.pem, and then setting env.CLOUDKIT_PRIVATE_KEY to the contents, removing the header/suffix and any newlines.
The CloudKit docs are pretty vague and I'm not sure exactly what I could be doing wrong.
Example call:
await cloudKitRequest({
        operations: {
            operationType: 'create',
            recordName: 'randomuuid',
            record: {
                recordType: 'MyRecord',
                fields: {
                    name: {
                        value: 'Test Name',
                    }
                },
            },
        },
    },
    'POST',
    'public/records/modify',
    context.env
)


The docs specify "Compute the ECDSA signature of this message with your private key.", so ECDSA should be correct here. I'm not entirely sure what node crypto is doing but I assume it infers ecdsa from the "-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----" header.

I have updated the question to include a sample function call. I'm not really able to provide an MCVE since this is using the CloudKit API and I'm not sure how they are verifying signatures on the backend other than what the docs specify, so I don't think providing a generated signature will be very helpful. I'm also not able to compare signatures between the two implementations due to the random factor of ECDSA, even with a fixed date.

Correct, I don’t know anything about the iCloud servers beyond the docs and I have been speculating for hours myself and have not been able to come up with a solution. Perhaps someone else will have implemented this before or will be able to see the difference in my two implementations :-)

The main problem seems to be different signature formats. The crypto module generates an ASN.1/DER encoded ECDSA signature by default, while WebCrypto generates an ECDSA signature in P1363 format. Apparently the service requires the ASN.1/DER format, so you have to convert the format accordingly.

Ah this was the issue, it is now working after converting to DER. I will post a more detailed answer, thanks for the help!

As discovered here,
The issue with the WebCrypto code is that it generates a signature in the P1363 format, while the CloudKit API expects a ASN.1/DER format signature. Converting to DER after generating the signature fixes the authentication failed error.
Example conversion code:
function convertToDER(signature: Uint8Array): Uint8Array {
    const r = signature.slice(0, 32)
    const s = signature.slice(32, 64)
    const rDer = toDERElement(r)
    const sDer = toDERElement(s)

    const derSequenceLength = rDer.length + sDer.length + 2
    const derArray = new Uint8Array(derSequenceLength)

    derArray[0] = 0x30
    derArray[1] = rDer.length + sDer.length

    derArray.set(rDer, 2)
    derArray.set(sDer, 2 + rDer.length)

    return derArray
}

function toDERElement(component: Uint8Array): Uint8Array {
    let i = 0
    while (i < component.length - 1 && component[i] === 0 && (component[i + 1] & 0x80) === 0) {
        i++
    }
    const strippedComponent = component.slice(i)

    const leadingZero = (strippedComponent[0] & 0x80) !== 0
    const length = strippedComponent.length + (leadingZero ? 1 : 0)
    const derElement = new Uint8Array(length + 2)

    derElement[0] = 0x02
    derElement[1] = length

    if (leadingZero) {
        derElement[2] = 0x00
        derElement.set(strippedComponent, 3)
    } else {
        derElement.set(strippedComponent, 2)
    }

    return derElement
}

Updated signMessage:
const signMessage = async (privateKey: CryptoKey, message: string) => {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder()
    const encodedMessage = encoder.encode(message)

    const p1363Signature = await crypto.subtle.sign(
        {
            name: 'ECDSA',
            hash: { name: 'SHA-256' },
        },
        privateKey,
        encodedMessage
    )

    // Convert P1363 format to ASN.1/DER format
    const derSignature = convertToDER(new Uint8Array(p1363Signature))

    return btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(derSignature)))
}


Note that this implementation does not work reliably: In the ASN.1/DER encoding, r and s are minimal-sized signed big-endian byte sequences (see here). Your implementation does not take the minimal-sized into account (compare e.g. with KJUR.crypto.ECDSA.hexRSSigToASN1Sig()). Also: For those who want to extend this to larger curves like P-521, consider this.
